# C++: What does template<class> mean?

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I'm trying to understand some C++ code. I'm an experienced Java programmer trying to learn C++. I've already read some exhaustive articles on templates, but no one of them answered me what does the following template specification mean.

```
template<
    template<template<class> class, class> class VisualOdometryTT, 
    template<class> class NodeBuilderTT,
    class PoseGraphT> 
class VORosInterface{ ... };
```

The part I don't understand is `template<class>` where I think some type specification is missing. But the code compiles without problems.

Comment: search for "template template parameters".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `NodeBuilderTT` as an example because it's easier:

`NodeBuilderTT` is a template parameter that is itself a template having one parameter -- let's call that `Z`.

You could have chosen to formally name `Z` and the code would compile just the same:

```
template<class Z> class NodeBuilderTT
```

So far this is quite similar to declaring function arguments:

```
void foo(int x) {}   // works
void foo(int)   {}   // also works
```

However, with the functions you would typically use the name `x` inside the function body. With templates you *cannot* use `Z` in the definition of `VORosInterface`, so there is absolutely no point in naming it and it is idiomatic to write

```
template<class> class NodeBuilderTT
```

My thanks to K-ballo for helping set the record straight here.

Comment: Even if you cared enough to name it, it is meaningless as you can't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Now it's clear to me, but the deeper I dig into C++ the more I love Java :-D

Comment: @K-ballo : You say if I wrote `template<template<class T> class NodeBuilderTT> class VORosInterface{ ... };` I couldn't use `T` as a type parameter in the class body?

Comment: @peci1: Exactly, `T` is meaningless there as the argument takes a _class-template_, not an _instantiated-template_. `T` is a parameter without a corresponding argument.

Comment: @K-ballo: Too long away from real code :/. Will be deleting the answer in a little while, you 're welcome to add one of your own.

Comment: @K-ballo: ...which is actually kind of necessary because I cannot delete an accepted answer it seems. :-)

Comment: Jon: The first part of your answer nails it, no need to delete it. Just remove the second part and add that it is meaningless to name the _template template-argument's argument_.

Comment: A closer parallel is using a pointer to function as a function argument: In `void f( void (*ptr)(int n) ) {}`, you can't actually use `n`.